# Почему функция дает разный результат?

Tags: javascript

```js
function sum(a){
  var s = a
 var d = function (b){
     s += b;
     return d
  }
   d.toString = function(){
      return s;
   }
   return d;
}

console.log( sum(2)(3)(3) )
```

```js
function sum(a){
  var s = a
 var d = function (b){
    return s += b;
  }
   d.toString = function(){
      return s;
   }
   return d;
}

console.log( sum(2)(3) )
```

Comment: _Функция дает разный результат?_ - очевидно да, достаточно просто запустить сниппеты в вопросе. Ответ на вопрос "Почему?" тоже очевиден - потому что приведены **разные** функции

Comment: @Grundy  почему мы 1 случае можем запускать функцию сколько хочешь а в втором случае нет ?

Comment: потому что в первом случае у тебя есть функция, которую можно запускать, а во втором - нет

Comment: @Grundy получается функция будет выполнять вычисления в нашем случае s += b; без разницы как как как она вызвана d() или d  в последнем случае d  мы просто преобразуем благодаря toString ?

Comment: не понял что ты написал.

Comment: @Grundy вот так d() мы получим результат return d вот так без скобок мы получим код функции

Comment: @Grundy если мы вызываем без скобок вычисления которые находятся в функции d будут вычисляться и записываться в s где s находится внешней функции ?

Comment: мы не получаем **код** функции.

Comment: **Нельзя** функцию **вызвать без скобок**

Comment: @Grundy вызываем функцию console.log( sum(2) ) она возвращает функцию  d и записывает результат во внешней s;  а затем эта функция благодаря d.toString в console.log( sum(2) ) преобразуется в число ?

Comment: `console.log` плохой пример, он может и не вызывать `.toString()`. Конкретно в сниппете вызывается `.toString()` у аргументов, потому что функция переопределена библиотекой, но в общем верно: `sum(2)` возвращает функцию, дальше вызывается переопределенный `toString` и выводится число

Comment: @Grundy  в функцию  sum возвращается функция а разве не будет unedfined ведь там b  не определена s += b  == unedfined ? .toString() ведь тогда получит unedfined  ?

Comment: _там b не определена s += b == unedfined ? .toString() ведь тогда получит unedfined ?_ - не понял что тут написано.

Comment: @Grundy console.log( sum() ) возвращает функцию function (b){ s += b return d } у нас же  b  не определена а значит undefined получается s += b ==  undefined  .toString() вернет undefined  ?

Comment: `b` - это параметр. покажи где ты **вызываешь** эту функцию, чтобы в этот параметр что-то пришло.

Comment: @Grundy  получается b сработает если функция будет вызываться а так s += b; b - игнор ?

Comment: `b` не сработает, - это просто параметр. Если функция не вызывается, очевидно ее тело не выполняется

Comment: @Grundy спасибо хоть что-то стало понятно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Содержательная часть первого фрагмента:

```
 s += b;
 return d;
```

Содержательная часть второго фрагмента:

```
return s += b;
```

В первом случае вы возвращаете функцию, соответственно код работает так как вы можете её вызвать по цепочке. Во втором случае вы возвращаете число, которое не функция, и потому вы видите ошибку `TypeError: ... is not a function` при попытке её вызвать. Т.о. во втором случае у вас ошибка.

Comment: почему мы 1 случае можем запускать функцию сколько хочешь а в втором случае нет ?

Comment: Потому что ваша функция возвращает просто число, а его нельзя вызвать повторно сколько хочешь. Его вообще нельзя использовать как функцию.

Comment: получается функция будет выполнять вычисления в нашем случае s += b; без разницы как как как она вызвана d() или d в последнем случае d мы просто преобразуем благодаря toString ? –

Comment: Да, примерно так